# What is the in-universe reason for Yon-Rogg to look like a human?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In the movie *Captain Marvel*, besides Mar-Vell, Yon-Rogg is the only Kree with light human skin. I can understand that Mar-Vell is disguised as a human, [probably using the same method as Vin-Tak on Agents of SHIELD](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Vin-Tak), but what is the case for Yon-Rogg, since in MCU all Krees have either Blue or [for unknown reasons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133328/korath-the-pursuer) Dark skin?

I know that in some instances of other Marvel media Yon-Rogg -just as many other Kree- has light skin, so it could make sense to portray him like this on the movie. However, I'm looking for an **in-universe reason**, since this character deviates a lot from the looks of the Kree race that have already been established in previous MCU movies and series ([EARTH-199999](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kree/Alternate_Realities#Earth-199999)), where a Kree can only change its skin color artificially.

*Please be polite, people that go to see this movie do not have the obligation to know every single detail in the comics (even a MCU fan don't have to). I'm just trying to see it **their way**, since this color change could lead them to confusion and I'm sure some of them will come here looking for answers.*

Comment: _"this character deviates a lot from the looks of the Kree race"_ have you any canon source for this or have you just assumed what the Kree race looks like from the few you've seen in MCU products to date?

Comment: It could be just as in the comics. Due to the interbreeding between alien races under the mighty Kree empire, yon-rogg could be one of the non-pure breed Kree.. however I cannot confirm that if the MCU I’d following the same reason

Comment: Although you are asking specifically about lighter skin, as per your title, Korath looks pretty human to me too.

Comment: So kree can be Blue and Black, but not Pink? Ok.

Answer (score 14):

> *I can understand that Mar-Vell is disguised as a human*

Then you can understand wrong. In the Marvel comic universe (which admittedly isn't the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but we'll get to that later) the following is the case with the [Kree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kree).

*"True Kree resemble humans almost exactly, with the exception of blue skin"*

*"The original Kree had blue-colored skin, but a second racial group with pink skin resembling that of human Caucasians emerged over the millennia. The blue-skinned "purebred" Kree have become a small, but powerful, minority"*

I may of course be wrong, but, personally I've seen no reason in any MCU products (I've seen) to date to believe that anything other than the above also holds true for the MCU.

Though I've little doubt that for the purposes of the MCU non-Caucasian actors & actresses may very well be used whenever convenient (or desired) without blue skin makeup & it will simply be retconned that the "pink skin" Kree of the comics includes the full range of skin tones found in humans.

> *since in MCU all Krees have either Blue or for unknown reasons Dark skin*

Once again, I believe your understanding is wrong & probably predicated on too small a sample of individuals to really be considered a valid observation, ^ see above.

So, in short, the answer to your titular question.

> *What is the in-universe reason for Yon-Rogg to look like a human*

Is simply, **because his species does**.. it's just what they happen to look like, blue skin Kree are a minority & pink skin Kree who look exactly like humans are far more common in their population.

*All that aside you're likely to see more blue skin Kree in MCU simply because they "look" more alien & are more easily identified by the viewer as "Kree", which is easy for the MCU to explain by simply saying Kree society is heavily stratified by class & the blue skins being the higher cast despite being a minority tend to be the majority of those in the military & that otherwise get off-world.*

If you won't accept the Wikipedia link then there's also [Digital Spy](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a25901968/kree-mcu-captain-marvel-supreme-intelligence/) & [Marvel Fandom](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kree).

Comment: Apparently aliens that look like humans with blue skin and weird eyes and maybe facial ridges were not human looking enough for them.

Comment: Can you refer to **MCU canonical sources**? I'm looking for in-universe reasons. Please point me to a case in any **movie or series** where I can find a non-blue Kree that is not cloaking itself.

Comment: Watch Agents of SHIELD season 2, Episode 12 "Who You Really Are", where a Kree soldier has to use nitrogen to change his skin color and go look the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133328/korath-the-pursuer) and comments for more ideas on "Blue Skin".

Comment: Also you can watch all Agents of Shield, especially season 5 which have a lot of Kree, none of them is pink. I can't find any pink Kree on Guardians of the Galaxy either but if you can correct me on this I'll appreciate it.

Comment: I've seen all the Agents of Shield episodes & I know there's nothing in any of them to back up your beliefs about the MCU Kree, yes practically all if not all of those we see in it are blue, so what, that doesn't mean anything ~ the main reason nearly all those we see are blue is I'm sure for no other reason than they look cooler & also because it makes it easy for the viewer to know who the bad guys are if they're all blue.

Comment: @LudovicoN, on the train Yon-Rogg and Vers/Carol are taking just before she meets the Supreme Intelligence, several other pink-skinned Kree are seen in the background.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Thanks, I'll look for it. They could be from other planet, you know...? but if they are Kree that is a real fact that there are other "pink" Krees on the MCU. May even be an answer...

Comment: ^ @KeithMorrison Which is why I won't edit it into this answer, you deserve the points for it on your own answer, especially if you can find a pic or something to link in.

Comment: @LudovicoN and Pelinore, you both need to lighten up and be polite to each other. Take a break from the computer and get some fresh air if you need to.

Comment: While thoughtful, this answer does not actually provide anything from the MCU as to why Yon-Rogg or Mar-Vell are not blue. I checked both of your links, and neither provides any kind of in-universe answer. -1

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from  [Wikipedia - Kree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kree#Biology):

> The original Kree had blue-colored skin, **but a second racial group**
>   with pink skin **resembling that of human Caucasians** emerged over the
>   millennia. The blue-skinned "purebred" Kree have become a small, but
>   powerful, minority. Pink Kree are much more durable than their blue
>   racial brethren.

In short, just like humans, the Kree too have morphologically distinct races within the species.

Yon Rogg seems to be a member of the pink race.

Beyond this, *why* the character was portrayed to be a pink Kree, is no longer "in-universe".

That becomes an out-of-universe question.

I think a better question would be that "Why were all the Kree we have seen so far Blue skinned".

And that is because so far, we have only seen Kree who were very powerful beings (either physically powerful, or socio-politically powerful), or associated to such beings.

Since Blue Kree are the "purebred" race, it's a good chance that they hold all the positions of power, and hence by correlation, we saw more of them.

So in theory, we could use this logic to explain why all powerful kree were blue(which is the "purebred" race). But now, Blue Kree are a minority on Hala. The Pink Kree are the common populace.

What are the kree we saw so far in the MCU + TV universe?

- Ronan: A high figure.
- Kree Reapers: Pretty powerful figures.
- Family of Kaisus: The most powerful Kree family.

Korath was the first exception we saw in the MCU, which hinted that Kree could also be non-Blue naturally.

So in short: The reason we didn't see any non-Blue kree so far, is because all the Kree we saw so far were people of power, and Blue kree hold that position on their home-world Hala.